# Google pie chart (any chart) not working inside an ASP.Net AJAX Update Panel

Tags: asp.net-ajax, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I am facing problem with Google pie chart and Update panel.
Their is one Tab container inside a update panel which has two Tab panels.
Each tab panel contains div and script to plot Google pie chart.
when first time page gets load it works properly. but if i change the tab then pie chart doesn't work.
i have used  "Sys.Application.add_load(methodname) inside each tab panel.
i have used script which is in Google play.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `google.load` only loads the Visualization API and fires a callback the first time it is called only.  Subsequent calls to `google.load` for the same package do nothing.  If your charts draw in a callback from the google loader in your second tab, the callback will not fire, so you need to use a callback from the update process instead.